# Why the body of my lambda expression in member function is not executed?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Recently I have been studying lambda expressions and following lambda code surprises me:

```
#include <iostream>

class lambda_this_test
{
private:
    int mNumber;
public:
    lambda_this_test()
    {
        mNumber = 11;
    };
    void print_member()
    {
        //lambda expression
        [this]{mNumber = 12; std::cout<< "mNumber = \n"<<mNumber<<std::endl;};
    }
};

int main()
{
    lambda_this_test testClass;

    testClass.print_member();
}
```

When executed, no prints can be seen so that it seems body of the lambda expression is not executed at all, and then I use gdb to prove this because there is no code in print_member() function.

May I ask what's wrong with my usage of lambda?

Answer (score 11):

It looks that you have forgotten to execute your lambda expression; you should add parens:

```
[this]{mNumber = 12; cout<< "mNumber = \n"<<mNumber<<endl;} ();
//                                                          ^^
```

That is, the below statement:

```
[this]{mNumber = 12; cout<< "mNumber = \n"<<mNumber<<endl;};
```

only declares a lambda expression. Alternatively, you could write:

```
auto lambda = [this]{mNumber = 12; cout<< "mNumber = \n"<<mNumber<<endl;};

lambda();
```

Comment: Hi,it seems one of the formal style of lambda expression is
[capture-list](parametr){body}, what's your last "()"  mean?

Comment: @LiuNick: yes, when you declare lambda, this is how it looks like: [capture-list](parametr){body}; but this is just like declaring a function - it won't work until you invoke it. `lambda()` executes the body of your lambda, and the lambda itself can be "inlined", `[capture-list](parametr){body}();` calls your lambda

Answer (score 0):

thanks Piotr S, this is clear now. Lambda expression is to declare the closure object. and body of lambda expressin is inside the operator() of that closure object, so if the body need to be executed, then operator() shoud be invoked.